# Using Node.js and Express.js in Chrome-Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a chrome extension that connects to **salesforce** using **oauth2** flow provided by **JSforce.js** but all the examples I found online contain functionality provided by **Node.js** and **Express.js**, how can I add them to my application scope, without requiring the user to download them before using the application. Can anyone clarify this issue to me, I am getting a bit confused here. Thanks!

EDIT:

I got this example from here :   [link](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#oauth2)

This is the Oauth2 code that uses express.js framework to run:

```
 var jsforce = require('jsforce');
//
// OAuth2 client information can be shared with multiple connections.
//
var oauth2 = new sf.OAuth2({
  // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
  // loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com',
  clientId : '<your Salesforce OAuth2 client ID is here>',
  clientSecret : '<your Salesforce OAuth2 client secret is here>',
  redirectUri : '<callback URI is here>'
});
//
// Get authz url and redirect to it.
//
app.get('/oauth2/auth', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({ scope : 'api id web' }));
});

// Pass received authz code and get access token
//
app.get('/oauth2/callback', function(req, res) {
  var conn = new sf.Connection({ oauth2 : oauth2 });
  var code = req.param('code');
  conn.authorize(code, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    // Now you can get the access token, refresh token, and instance URL information.
    // Save them to establish connection next time.
    console.log(conn.accessToken);
    console.log(conn.refreshToken);
    console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
    console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
    console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
    // ...
  });
});
```

**require(), app.get(), sf.Oauth2()** are objects/functions provided by Node.js and Express.js which I cannot use

Comment: I think it would helpful if you add a couple of those examples or at least link them if those are big.

Comment: @wOxxOm I edited as you suggested. By the way how come I always see you at every chrome-extension post. You are a really dedicated user :)

Comment: Not my area of expertise but I think it should be possible to use the libraries without node.js even if it's not easy (you'll have to read the official documentation on apps and do a lot of experimenting/googling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is not meant to be run on the browser or in a chrome extension, you should use the web-browser setup following [these instructions](https://jsforce.github.io/start/#web-browser) and adding [jsforce.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.5.0/jsforce.min.js) to your extension's page.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that instructions but they seem a bit unclear, for me at least. They say that I have to use a proxy server that can run Node.js and the provide the proxy url in the app init setup, but I am not sure how to start the server using Node.js, never done this before. Moreover how to integrate everything inside the app. If you managed to do this, or something similar would you mind  sharing this piece of information  with me? Thanks!

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but how to get started with node is a bit too broad a question to answer here. The guides for both jsforce.js and jsforce-ajax-proxy (the only server side component you need) are not too long and really straightforward, so once you have a server set up you shouldn't have too much trouble. [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html) and [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) have free plans and make it really easy to start a nodejs service.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot I will start looking into it. And if I do have any issues I will post comments below.